# (blender bpy) How to add a Cycle Modifier to a Bone's F-Curve in GRAPH_EDITOR

Tags: python, scripting

everyone!

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context

areatype = context.area.type
context.area.type = 'GRAPH_EDITOR' 
ob = context.object
action = ob.animation_data.action
bpy.ops.graph.fmodifier_add(type='CYCLES')
context.area.type = areatype
```

[image: Graph Editor showing modifiers and selections]
In the above code
The above code only responds to the active f-curve.
I need to access other channels with a script.
Is there any way to adapt the cycle modifie?

---

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/242554/89484

On lemon's advice, I was able to adapt the cycle modifier.

It just didn't work for some reason.
Once I made a meaningless move in the graph editor, the cycle modifier was successfully applied.

Here is the code.

```
import bpy

o=bpy.context.object
action = o.animation_data.action
for c in action.fcurves: m = c.modifiers.new('CYCLES')




context = bpy.context
areatype = context.area.type
context.area.type = 'GRAPH_EDITOR' 
ob = context.object
action = ob.animation_data.action

#This is a meaningless operation.
bpy.ops.anim.channels_setting_enable(type='PROTECT')
bpy.ops.anim.channels_setting_disable(type='PROTECT')

context.area.type = areatype
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's one 'gotcha' with the Cycles modifier.  It has to be the first modifier in the fcurve modifier stack.  Here's a modified version of the script that generates an error message if the there are modifiers on the stack but there isn't a Cycles modifier.  I looked into pulling all of the other modifiers and then replacing them, but that's a lot of code, and perhaps the error message is enough?

````
import bpy

def enable_cycles_modifiers(action):
    """ Enable the cycles modifier on all F-Curves in this action
        except those that already have modifiers, because the
        cycles modifier must be first.
    """
    for fcurve in action.fcurves:
        modifiers = fcurve.modifiers

        if not len(modifiers):
            modifier = modifiers.new('CYCLES')
            continue
        
        if modifiers[0].type == 'CYCLES':
            continue
        
        print(f'Cannot add Cycles modifier to {action.name} F-curve {fcurve.data_path}[{fcurve.array_index}]')

            
object = bpy.context.object
if object and object.animation_data:
    action = object.animation_data.action
    enable_cycles_modifiers(action)
    
scene = bpy.context.scene
scene.frame_set(scene.frame_current)
```
````

Comment: Thank you.
Marty Fouts.
I was able to adapt the cycle modifier in your script as well.
However, I was never able to get the animation to actually work. Is this a bug?
https://i.imgur.com/DFK8jCG.gif

Comment: what specifically still isn't working?  Is it worth asking another question?

Comment: Check the GIF animation of the link.  Although the cycle modifier has been adapted.  However, the actual animation doesn't work for some reason.http://imgur.com/DFK8jCG

Comment: Your script worked fine! Thanks for the nice function! Was saved!

Answer (score 6):

You can do something like that using [`bpy.types` apis](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.html):

```
action = o.animation_data.action
for c in action.fcurves: m = c.modifiers.new('CYCLES')
```

`m` is the modifier object that you can use to change its parameters.

The documentation is [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.FCurveModifiers.html#bpy.types.FCurveModifiers.new) and [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.FModifier.html#fmodifier-bpy-struct).

To force updates, you can add somthing like this which reset the current frame:

```
s = bpy.context.scene
s.frame_set(s.frame_current)
```

Comment: Thanks!

But for some reason, the cycle doesn't get triggered until I take action in the graph editor once...?
https://imgur.com/NosPRja